# what's the limit size of the magento image?

Tags: php, magento

if i want the product image to have the following functioin,
[image]

when i upload a small image, it will not show the function,except i uploaded an enough large image,what's the smallest size of the image when installed magento with default state. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the display size of the containing element. Look at the JavaScript functions in the default included "product.js" file. You'll find this in lines 58-64:

```
    if (this.imageDim.width <= this.containerDim.width
        && this.imageDim.height <= this.containerDim.height) {
        this.trackEl.up().hide();
        this.hintEl.hide();
        this.containerEl.removeClassName('product-image-zoom');
        return;
    }
```

Where `this.containerDim` is the parent node of the image element (`$(imageEl).parentNode`). (I think default is a `p` tag with `class="product-image"`).

Try changing the display size of the P tag to something smaller and re-initialize the Product.Zoom method with the appropriate parameters and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves me correctly that will be 265 pixels on default theme. *But nobody uses the default Magento product zoom viewer, you need to roll your own or go onto 'connect' to get something better.*